# Symfony2 & phpunit: enable method override

Tags: symfony, phpunit, x-http-method-override

I just started on a Symfony2 project. The CRUD generation tool created a default controller and functional test, which I'm modifying to suit my needs. The edit-form generated by the controller creates the following HTML:

```html
<form action="/app_dev.php/invoice/7" method="post" >
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT" />
    <!-- ... -->
</form>
```

I like the approach of overriding the HTTP method, because it enables me to create semantic routes in my application. Now I'm trying to test this form with a functional test, using the following:

```
$crawler = $client->click($crawler->selectLink('Edit')->link());
$form = $crawler->selectButton('Edit')->form(array(
    '_method' => 'PUT',
    // ...
));

$client->submit($form);
$this->assertEquals(302, $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode(), "Unexpected HTTP status code for POST /invoice/<id>/edit");
```

When I execute the tests by running `phpunit -c /app`, my tests fails because the status code is 405 instead of the expected 302.

With a bit of debugging I found out that the response of is a `MethodNotAllowedHttpException`. Appearantly, when running the test through PHPUnit, the [method overriding](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/routing/method_parameters.html) (which internally maps a POST request in combination with `_method=PUT` param to a PUT request) doesn't take place.

That said, my question is: **when executing my PHPUnit tests, why doesn't symfony recongize the overwritten method?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument of `form` method is a http method. So try this:

```
$form = $crawler->selectButton('Edit')->form(array(
    // ...
), 'PUT');
```

Comment: That solution has come to my mind, but I've tried to avoid it because I want my functional tests to simulate browser requests. As I've not been able to come up with a more appropriate solution, I'll implement it this way.